# Send Maven output to console and log file using pom

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, pom.xml, eclipse-luna

**Question**: When running Maven in Eclipse, how do I send the console output to file?

I would like to achieve this using a pom setting or a maven plugin. I do **not** want to modify the run configurations or the maven system settings.

For reference, I am using Windows 7, Eclipse Luna, Java 6, Maven 3.

Comment: You can't do that, the answers you have are the only way to go. How would Maven be able to write a file, before it has read the POM? Consider multi-module project also, where that configuration would only be in a module.

Comment: Try using AOP. Was successful in redirecting logs to file by applying point cut on the default org.apache.maven.plugin.logging.Log. But too much effort for nothing. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As per [official command line options](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-embedder/cli.html) you could use `-l,--log-file <arg>` which provide the:

> Log file where all build output will go.

As such, running:

```
mvn clean install -l output.log
```

Would not print anything to the console and automatically redirect the **whole build output** to the `output.log` file.

If you don't want to type it every time (or you actually don't want to use the command line) and you want it as default option (although rare case I would suppose), you could use new command line options behavior available since version [3.3.1](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/release-notes.html) and have a `.mvn` folder where the concerned `pom.xml` file is located and a `maven.config` file in it simply providing the following line:

```
-l output.log
```

That is, the `.mvn/maven.config` file replaces `MAVEN_OPTIONS` just for its project, **locally** where it has been created, with the options it provides, not impacting other builds as per Maven settings of `MAVEN_OPTIONS`.

This is an IDE agnostic solution (it's a new built-in feature of Maven) and local to a project, but still not provided via simple POM editing, which cannot be achieved since the first phase of [Maven default life cycle phases](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) is `validate`, which:

> validate the project is correct and all necessary information is available

That is, during the build, hence when the build **has already started** (and generated output), it validates the `pom.xml` file, hence too late to redirect build output at that stage based on some POM properties/plugin.

Comment: Even though logging in the Eclipse console window is lost, this is the most reasonable answer.

Answer (score 6):

Go to run as and choose `Run Configuration -> Commons -> Select a file`.
This should redirect your output to the file you specified.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I am looking for some way to achieve this by modifying the pom only.  I have updated my question.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](https://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html) you can try editing the `${MAVEN_HOME}/conf/logging/simplelogger.properties`. I gave it a quick try and maven's output is redirected, but anything else writing to `stdout` (tests, for instance) still writes on the console

Comment: This is correct, but I am looking for a solution that does not modify the maven settings.

Comment: Yep, I hoped you could override those settings in the `<properties>`  section of the project file but it doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 2):

What about creating a fork of M2E and modifying it to read the output file for the launch config from pom.xml

https://github.com/eclipse/m2e-core.git

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is setting the output format in the `mvn file`. For example, in the directory `/usr/bin`, add the desired output informing the path the log will be saved at the end of `exec "$JAVACMD" \` line: *| tee /home/maven-log.log*.

However, it only works when the maven is called by terminal line; when called by IDEs, like eclipse, this solutions does not work.